# SQL-запрос, возвращающий два стлобца по условию

Tags: sql, postgresql

Я не специалист в SQL, поэтому допускаю, что спрашиваю элементарную вещь, но ответа я не нашел, а очень нужно.

Имеется таблица table, в которой помимо всего прочего есть два столбца first_id и second_id. Как вывести два столбца так,чтобы в первом были first_id where second_id = 0, а во втором - first_id where second_id = 1 ? База postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть так:

```
SELECT
       CASE WHEN second_id = 0 THEN first_id ELSE NULL END,
       CASE WHEN second_id = 1 THEN first_id ELSE NULL END
FROM table_
```

Answer (score 0):

как варик так

```
SELECT
   t.first_id,
   tj.first_id
FROM table t
JOIN (SELECT first_id 
    FROM table t2 
    WHERE second_id = 1) tj 
  ON tj.first_id = t1.first_id
WHERE second_id = 0;
```

Comment: Видимо, вкрались опечатки. Что такое t1.first_id?

Comment: Так заработает только в одном случае, если в таблице на каждый second_id=0 есть строго одна запись с таким же first_id и second_id=1, что в жизни бывает очень редко. любые записи которым не нашлось пары данный запрос не выведет

Comment: ГОП-proger detected.

Comment: @Hermann Zheboldov, SELECT
   t.first_id,
   tj.first_id
FROM table t1
JOIN (SELECT first_id 
    FROM table t2 
    WHERE second_id = 1) tj 
  ON tj.first_id = t1.first_id
WHERE second_id = 0;

Comment: @Mike, об этом не подумал